# Adding authentication to a Silverlight 4 RIA services application (not the business template)

Tags: silverlight, authentication, wcf-ria-services

I started a Silverlight 4 RIA Services application with the Navigation Application template,
instead of the Business Application template.

Now I want to add authentication to that application (to protect a page from unauthenticated users)

I've added an AuthenticationService to the project,
but I'm not sure what the steps are now to get it actually working and there doesn't seem to be a way to "upgrade" to the business application template.

I can add the [RequiresAuthentication] attribute to some of the normal service methods,
but I cannot figure out how to allow the user to log in or prevent a user from opening a specific page.

Is there any guidance for an "upgrade" like this?

Comment: Found a solution (completely different from what I read in the books or blogs): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707353(VS.91).aspx but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the hosting ASP.Net App to enable forms authentication, which will probably require the configuration of an authentication provider.

Try this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707353(VS.91).aspx

- edit: doh moments too late ;)

Comment: No problem, it helped :) thnx